# Laravel incorrect database name after cloning from git

Tags: laravel, git, laravel-8

i cloned my project from git with ssh key and now my env file has changed. it keeps saying i have the wrong database name no matter whatever artisan command i try out.

Does somebody know what im supposed to fill in it? I forgot what the database name was in my last env file. i lost the other project.

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'laravel' (SQL: select * from `permission`)

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:678
    674▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    675▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    676▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    677▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 678▕             throw new QueryException(
    679▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    680▕             );
    681▕         }
    682▕ 

  • Database name seems incorrect: You're using the default database name `laravel`. This database does not exist.
    
    Edit the `.env` file and use the correct database name in the `DB_DATABASE` key.
```

this is a part of my env file:

```
PP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

Comment: Does the database exist?

Comment: No. i cant migrate. if i migrate it shows that message

Comment: Create it via your database's command-line. Migrations won't create it for you

Comment: How? i pretty much tried every command possible i think and it shows same error over and over.

Comment: Go to phpmyadmin or mysql, create database name "laravel" and then run command, It will work.

Answer (score 0):

check config/database.php in connection some developer write database configuration their

Comment: no. cant find database name there. + its my project, i am the developer lol

Comment: last but not least you can try a new database with a new username and password then run the migration command.